# Odoo[v9] store files in filesystem

Tags: filesystems, odoo

My question is about storing different files in the filesystem and not in the database. I am using Odoo version 9 and everything I found is for Odoo[v8]...

I have read something about a "default" storelocation, but I could not find it in the filesystem... Does anybody know where I can find this?

I also tried to set a parameter to the "binary" field, but this does not work. When I like to save my entry Odoo tells me, that I have maybe forgotten a required field... Here is my code:

```
class product_file(models.Model):
   _name = 'product.file'

   name = fields.Char(string='Bezeichnung', required=True)
   description = fields.Text(string='Beschreibung')
   data_file = fields.Binary(string="Datei", required=True, attachment=True)
```

Can anyone please help me!

Thank you

**Edit:**

Found the solution:

If you want to use the parameter "attachment" you are not allowed to set the field as required... That was my mistake

And the other point, yes, the default location can be found in the config-file (Thanks to Prakash Sharma)

Comment: Hi, on which operation system do you use odoo? And how did you install it?

Comment: thanks for your edit info. its a usefull information, might use it someday.

Answer (score 0):

set **data_dir** (like `data_dir = /path/to/desired/Odoo`) in odoo-server.conf file

Comment: Does this store a database file in that location - or the files themselves?

Answer (score 0):

There is **odoorc.conf** file in home folder :
set the path where you want to store the file in odoo.